# In ActionScript, fill stage with external SWF

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flash, mxml

**EDIT: I have since solved this problem by simply reworking my MXML-based app and using the SWFLoader component to get the desired effect, without any reloading necessary. This question is therefore no longer an issue for me, but I leave it open for reference.**

---

In MXML, I can get the desired effect easily:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
  layout="absolute">
  <mx:SWFLoader width="100%" height="100%"
    source="3298.swf"/>
</mx:Application>
```

It looks like this:

[(external SWF fills stage) http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/40036/screenshot_028_MSd0UZ.png](http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/40036/screenshot_028_MSd0UZ.png)

I'm new at ActionScript, though, so I can't quite figure out how to duplicate this without MXML. Here's the relevant class:

```
package {
  import flash.net.URLRequest;
  import flash.display.DisplayObject;
  import flash.display.Loader;
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class Asset extends Loader {
    public var id:int;
    private var preview:Preview;
    private var swfContent:DisplayObject;
    public var zone:int;

    public function Asset(data:Object) {
      id = data.id;
      zone = data.zone;
    }

    public function loadInto(previewToSet:Preview):void {
      preview = previewToSet;
      var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
      contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
      load(request);
    }

    private function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event):void {
      swfContent = loadEvent.currentTarget.content;
      swfContent.scaleX = 1;
      swfContent.scaleY = 1;
      preview.addChild(swfContent);
    }

    private function get url():String {
      return id + ".swf";
    }
  }
}
```

In the `loadInto` function I give the `Asset` a sprite to live on, and it starts to load. I can get pretty close by setting `scaleX` and `scaleY` each to 1, but I can't quite figure out why it's not at the top, and why the SWF is just a bit to large.

[(external swf slightly off) http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/40040/screenshot_029_4pHKNI.png](http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/40040/screenshot_029_4pHKNI.png)

How can I duplicate MXML's 100% height and width in pure ActionScript? Is it doable? If not, I have a fallback app in pure MXML, but my implementation there involves loading the SWFs every time I want to add or remove any one of them... it's not perfect. So I'd prefer this type of implementation if I can just figure out the sizing issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Note to world: currently playing with the thought of just using the MX SWFLoader component in the ActionScript itself. Not sure why that didn't occur to me at first.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [resize event](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#RESIZE) from the [stage object](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Stage.html) and each time the [resize event](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/events/Event.html#RESIZE) is fired resize the content according to that:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);

public function onResize(e:Event):void{
 swfContent.width=stage.stageWidth;
 swfContent.height=stage.stageHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
```

to the start of your class then size and place the loaded image to

```
loadedimage.x = loadedimage.y = 0;
loadedimage.width = stage.stageWidth;
loadedimage.height = stage.stageHeight;
```

Comment: This gets me closer: http://www.ubuntu-pics.de/bild/40045/screenshot_030_P8eB2D.png - I think there may be something sneaky going on with the SWF (I'm not the original author), since I remember on decompiling it that there was actual data stored in it instead of just a shape. I'll go back and see if I can find anything more useful there.

Comment: Nah, nothing particularly odd about the SWF that I can pick out. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

This sound like the anchor point of your swf is not precisely in it's corner. Try offsetting the x and y position in your code, or, even better, modifying the swf to have the anchor point in the corner ?